# Is $u \frac{dv}{du} + v (1+u) = u e^{u}$ a linear or nonlinear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having a hard time deciding if the following differential equation is linear or not because of the last term on the left handside.

$$u \frac{dv}{du} + v (1+u) = u e^{u}$$

Can $v$ be multiplied by a linear function of $u$ like $(1+u)$ and still make the differential equation linear?

Thank you

Comment: This equation is a linear ode.

Comment: Because: the map $v \mapsto u \frac{dv}{du} + v (1+u)$ is a linear transformation.

Comment: It would be an inhomogeneous llinear ode, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any equation first order of this form is linear:
$$y'+\alpha(x)y=\beta(x)$$
You DE is of that form
$$v'+\frac {u+1}{u}v=e^u
\implies v'+\alpha ({u})v=\beta(u)$$ 
So it's linear.

Answer (score 1):

The linearity of an ODE depends on the choice of the variable concerning the linearity. 
In your case, the equation is linear for the variable $v$, but it is non-linear for the variable $u$.

Answer (score -2):

The solution is given by $$v(u)=\frac{c_1 e^{-u}}{u}+\frac{e^u \left(\frac{u}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)}{u}$$

Comment: if the term $(1+u)$, which multiplies $v$, was squared $(1+u)^2$, would it still be a linear ode?

Comment: @bru1987  Yes it dosent matter what u is. Since your equation is linear in v.